# Concrete method in super class-abstract class

Tags: java, oop, template-method-pattern

I have an abstract class Shape, some sub classes and some methods to calculate area, perimeter and to draw the shape that are overridden. 
I'm trying to find a Template Method in the abstract class for this application but I can't think of any.
I haven't found any common methods which will be identical for all the shapes and will produce something on the GUI either.
I thought of having a method in the abstract class to compare the areas of two shapes but I can't get my head over how to do that since I think I can't I use this (referring to the instance of the class) in an abstract class.
Is there anything common for all shapes and what could be my template method?
Thank you.

Comment: You need something like `Shape#compareByArea(Shape anotherShape) { double area1 = this.getArea(); double area2 = anotherShape.getArea(); return (area1 > area2) ? 1 : (area1 < area2) ? -1 : 0; }`?

Comment: Why do you think you need a Template Method?

Comment: The task is to use Template Method Pattern and I can't see where I can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do areaEquals:

```
public abstract class Shape {
    public boolean areaEquals(Shape otherShape) {
        return this.area() == otherShape.area();
    }

    public abstract double area();
}
```

The whole idea is that the area calculation is something specific to each shape, but the comparison is common to all shapes that can calculate their own area.

Answer (score 0):

here your `compareArea()` is template method :

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Shape rec = new Rectangle();
    Shape sqr = new Square();
    int diff = rec.compareArea(sqr);
    System.out.println(diff);
 }
}

abstract class Shape{
public int compareArea(Shape otherShape){
    return computeArea() - otherShape.computeArea();
 }
abstract int computeArea();
}
class Square extends Shape{
int s = 2;
@Override
int computeArea() {
    return s * s;
 }
}
class Rectangle extends Shape{
int l = 3;
int b = 4;
@Override
int computeArea() {
    return l * b;
 }
}
```